# How to parse variable to Modal and from that to Ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, modal-dialog

Hi all and please forgive me if it's looks obvious to you, but Im struggling with this for some time now... I have an HTML table that list all of my customers, I want to enable a Delete option to each of the customer records but only after asking the user to select if he wants to delete the customer from 2 other systems as well: the Mantis (our bug tracking system) and Timesheet (our hours reporting system). I thought of a Modal with 2 checkbox but my questions are:

1. How can I parse the customer id to the Modal, I will need to parse each customer with his own id. Or maybe it's not needed at all?
2. How do I parse the Id from the Modal to the Ajax?  I've created a
   'Delete' button that works just fine but now I want to add this
   questions before, something like: "would you like to delete customer
   from all systems?" and let the user select 2 checkbox. The delete
   operation should consider the user selection.

Thank you for the help
    :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crudest but easiest way would be to put the `ID` in window. object that is global.

```
window.idToDelete = 123;
```

That way you can reach that variable from the `JavaScript` function you call upon pressing the delete button.

Comment: Do you mean setting each modal with a different id? that way I will have many modals, as many as the number of my table lines, did I got you right?

Comment: My idea was that you when pressing delete button you save the id in window.idToDelete, and then you call upon the modal window. From the modal window you call upon the delete function with what tables you want the user to be deleted from. And that function can access window.idToDelete that was previously set as it's global.
This is only a valid solution if you just have one modal window open at a time.

Comment: thank you, your explanation gave me the idea to use onclick with the button I used to open the modal, there I parsed the customer_id to my javascript and then set it to the modal submit button as a the button 'name'. from there to the ajax it was easy. thank you.